# Python-for-Android: Error compiling Cython file

Tags: cython, kivy

After git cloning python-for-android I tried creating a distribution:

```
./distribute.sh -m "kivy"
```

And got few errors of this kind:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        vertex_format.last_shader = self
        for i in xrange(vertex_format.vattr_count):
            attr = &vertex_format.vattr[i]
            if attr.per_vertex == 0:
                continue
            attr.index = glGetAttribLocation(self.program, <char *><bytes>attr.name)
                                                          ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kivy/graphics/shader.pyx:448:63: Casting temporary Python object to non-numeric non-Python type
```

Found [this answer](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/73), which did not solve my problem:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge cython
sudo pip install cython
```

Do I need a specific Cython version?

Thanks!

**Update**

Thanks to @RyanP I tried running:

```
cython -V
cython shader.pyx
```

Well, Cython version seems ok:

```
Cython version 0.21
```

But still, shader.pyx won't compile with the very same error.

**Another update**

I did both:

1. Used @inclement advice and removed both `build` and `dist` .
2. Used `export P4A_kivy_DIR=/path/to/cloned/kivy/`

And `dist/default` was finally created.

Comment: This code will build with Cython 0.21. If those instructions didn't work for you, then there is a problem on your system preventing you from running the correct Cython.

Comment: Thanks @RyanP I searched my entire system `find / -name "cython"` and found only cython 0.21

Comment: The problem is it's trying to compile a non-master pyjnius. Could you delete the `build` and `dist` folders in your python-for-android, and try again?

Comment: I think i encountered this try use ./distribute.sh -f -m "kivy==master" i think cython 0.21 does not work with kivy 1.8. maybe worth using master anyway as kivy 1.9 is not supposed to be that far away.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe this was build for Cython 0.21 but for Cython 0.20 try to install kivy with cython 0.20

> pip install cython==0.20

Here is a thread describing the issue

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cython-devel/2014-October/004210.html